# Jinja2 looping over list of dictionary items

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list of dictionary items I am looping over.
I can get the key which is the year, when I try to get the data in the dictionary it's printing the year again.

```
  [{'2020': [], '2019': ['05'], '2018': ['02', '01']}] 
  {% for d in  dirs %}
      {% for sd in d %}
     {{ sd }}
         {% for doy in sd %}   
            {{ doy }}<br>
         {% endfor %}<br><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Whats is printing is

```
 2020
 2
 0
 2
 0

2019
2
0
1
9

2018
2
0
1
8
```

What I want to print is

```
2020
2019
05
2018
02
01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can achieve that by modifying your third loop.
 To simplify:

```
list = [{'2020': [''], '2019': ['05'], '2018': ['02', '01']}]
```

Template:

```
{% for obj in list %}
  {% for obj2 in obj %}
    <p>{{ obj2 }}</p>
    {% for obj3 in obj[obj2] %}
     <p>{{ obj3 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
2020   
2019   
05   
2018  
02   
01
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
{% for doy in sd %}
```

to

```
{% for doy in d[sd] %}
```

---

The reasoning here is that iterating over a dictionary using the `for ... in ...` syntax iterates over the keys of the dictionary. That means that your nested loop was then attempting to loop over the values *within the key of the dictionary* rather than the value of the key of the dictionary.